# How to display a sfWidgetFormSelectRadio item without showing the label

Tags: symfony1, symfony-forms, symfony-1.4

I am using Symfony 1.3.6 on Ubuntu 10.0.4.

I am using the sfWidgetFormSelectRadio to allow a user to select a picture from a list, in a form.

In the action, the pictures are set up like this:

```
    $this->form->setWidget('chosenpic', new sfWidgetFormSelectRadio(array(
                            'choices' => $this->pictures,
                            'default' => $this->pictures[count($this->pictures)-1] ))
                            );
```

In the template, the widget is displayed like this:

```
<?php echo $form['chosenpic']->render(array('id'=>'check'.($i+1), 'value'=> ($i+1), 'width' => "80", 'height' => "80")); ?>
```

This generates the following output:

```
<ul class="radio_list"><li><input type="radio" width="80" height="80" id="check1" value="1" name="flowers[chosenpic]">&nbsp;<label for="flowers_chosenpic_0">http://example.com/media/images/48408000/jpg/_48408794_009829449-1.jpg</label></li></ul>
```

I do no want the the label for appearing, as it messes up the form. Short of manually generating the HTML myself (using the form and widget names, is there a way that I can prevent the widget from displaying a 'label for' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a custom formatter. In your form's configure function, do the following:

```
public function configure()
{
  $this->setWidget('chosenpic', new sfWidgetFormSelectRadio(array(
        'formatter' => array($this, 'pictureRadioFormatterCallback')
  )));
}
```

Then, add a formatter that doesn't render labels to your form:

```
public function pictureRadioFormatterCallback($widget, $inputs)
{
  $rows = array();
  foreach ($inputs as $input)
  {
    $rows[] = $widget->renderContentTag('li', $input['input']);
  }

  return !$rows ? 
    '' : 
    $widget->renderContentTag('ul', implode($widget->getOption('separator'), $rows), array('class' => $widget->getOption('class')));
}
```

However, ideally, you should be using the labels to display the images, rather than displaying the images outside of the labels. Also, it's typically a bad idea to be configuring widgets inside of an action, can that code go in it's own form?

Comment: Make a custom form (e.g. FrontendModelForm) and then pass the pictures into the form as an option. Or have the form itself perform whatever logic is necessary to retrieve the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the above -- or use CSS to hide the label generated by default ... something along the lines of:

```
ul.radio_list li input label { display: none; }
```

the form itself probably has an #id to help you better specify the CSS selector better. But if you like adding boilerplate PHP code to your app feel free :)